# How rename a column in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

The following will provide the default column name given the query

```
%python
df = sql("select last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1))")
display(df)
```

[image]

Can someone let me know how to change the column rename the column to say 'newname', instead of the default name **last_day(add_months(current_date(), -1))**

I've tried

```
%python
df = sql("select last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1)) as 'newname'")
```

But it didn't work

Comment: removing the single quotes in sql query should fix the error, `sql("select last_day(add_months(current_date(),-1)) as newname")`

Answer (score 0):

PySpark dataframes have `withColumnRenamed` function

You can use it as

```
df = df.withColumnRenamed('column_name', 'new_column_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try anyone from below:

```
df = df.selectExpr("add_months(current_date(),-1)) as newname")
```

---

```
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, "Table")
new_name_df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT add_months(current_date(),-1)) AS newname from Table")
new_name_df.show()
```

---

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = df.select(col("add_months(current_date(),-1))").alias("newname"))
```